# Can't create BluePrint, Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: blueprint

Clicking "Add Parent" to select a suitable parent publication when adding a new publication, a popup window appears which immediately closes.  Replicated in IE 10, IE 11, Chrome 31.0.1650.63.   Is there a bug or has the mechanism changed for creating a blueprint?

Answer (score 12):

By default creating a publication will only add a Building Block folder and Categories and Keyword and it will require you to Create a Structure Group manually. For a publication to act as a parent (or Base) it must have a Root structure group.

Answer (score 5):

One day, I will remember to create the Root SG in the base!

Comment: and I still hope, one day you will get a complete BluePrint in the system rather than having to (re)create it each time for a new system ;o)

Comment: I have downvoted this answer for a very specific reason. I actually believe that the question, and (in principle) the answer, are great. @mpaton - you need to improve this answer so that it makes sense to people who have not yet walked this road. Then I'll switch my downvote to an upvote.

Comment: I agree with Dominic and considering that it may be a bit difficult to understand to those who are both - New to SDL Tridion and are not native to English language :)
I have tried to add an answer in a simplified language - may be other professional would like to edit it :)